# Filter Fields on Jackson Serialization

Tags: json, serialization, tree, jackson, field

Jackson serializes an annotated object in a library. On a per-serialization basis, I want to tell Jackson which fields and sub-fields to serialize.

I have some tree of field names, and I only want to include those:

```
root
  |-sub_field_1
  |-sub_object_1
    |-sub_field_2
  |-sub_object_2
```

Without this feature, I would get something like:

```
{
  "sub_field_1":123,
  "sub_field_2":456,
  "sub_object_1":{
    "sub_field_1":123,
    "sub_field_2":456
  },
  "sub_object_2":{
    "sub_field_1":123,
    "sub_field_2":456
  }      
}
```

With this feature, I would get something like:

```
{
  "sub_field_1":123,
  "sub_object_1":{
    "sub_field_2":456
  },
  "sub_object_2":{
    "sub_field_1":123,
    "sub_field_2":456
  }      
}
```

I cannot use a SimpleBeanPropertyFilter, because different fields at different levels may share the same name.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to exclude specific fields from specific classes (ex: exclude "foo" from class Bar only), then you can try [genson library](http://owlike.github.io/genson/).

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().exclude("foo", Bar.class).create();
genson.serialize(yourObject);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work because, from above, "sub_object_1" and "sub_object_2" may be the same type, but their fields are being serialized differently.